# How to create a two buttons menu to be displayed side by side?

Tags: html, css

Need some guidance with this buttons menu I am trying to create. First of all I require spacing after each button so that there's a gap of seperation between the buttons.

Second I want the green list of buttons to be next to the red buttons list, not below and again a gap between these two buttons menu. How do I do this?

[image]

```
.btn-group1 a {
  background-color: red; 
  border: 1px solid white; 
  color: white; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  padding: 1em, 2em;
  width: 20%; 
  display: block; 
  font: medium bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.btn-group2 a {
  background-color: green; 
  border: 1px solid white; 
  color: white; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  padding: 1em, 2em;
  width: 20%; 
  display: block; 
  font: medium bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.btn-group a:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

.btn-group a:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


<div class="btn-container">      
         <div class="btn-group1">
        <a href="#">Introduction</a>
        <a href="#">Career Development - IT Support</a>
        <a href="#">Career Development - Testing</a>
      </div> 


      <div class="btn-group2">
          <a href="#">Lesson 1 - Methodologies and Development Lifecycle</a>
          <a href="#">Lesson Breakdown</a>
          <a href="#">Methodologies</a>
          <a href="#">Waterfall SDLC</a>
          <a href="#">Agile SDLC</a>
          <a href="#">Scrum vs Kanban</a>
          <a href="#">Ceremonies</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a flex to put them side by side:

```
.btn-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

as for the spacing add a margin bottom to the existing css for your classes:

```
.btn-group1 a {
  ...
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  ...
}

.btn-group2 a {
  ...
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  ...
}
```

Consider restructuring your css to remove dupe:

```
.btn-group a {
  border: 1px solid white; 
  color: white; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  padding: 1em, 2em;
  width: 20%; 
  display: block; 
  font: medium bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.btn-group1 a {
  background-color: red; 
}

.btn-group2 a {
  background-color: green; 
}

.btn-group a:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

.btn-group a:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}


<div class="btn-container">      
         <div class="btn-group btn-group1">
        <a href="#">Introduction</a>
        <a href="#">Career Development - IT Support</a>
        <a href="#">Career Development - Testing</a>
      </div> 


      <div class="btn-group btn-group2">
          <a href="#">Lesson 1 - Methodologies and Development Lifecycle</a>
          <a href="#">Lesson Breakdown</a>
          <a href="#">Methodologies</a>
          <a href="#">Waterfall SDLC</a>
          <a href="#">Agile SDLC</a>
          <a href="#">Scrum vs Kanban</a>
          <a href="#">Ceremonies</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I do have one more question if you don't mind. I want the menu to work responsively as well. So I was hoping when I make the browser screen smaller, the menu items suddenly go below each over, rather than next to each other, for my own learning can you show me how to achieve this responsiveness?

Comment: add a flex-wrap to your btn-container .i.e `.btn-container { ... flex-wrap: wrap; .. }`